# Php Class inside included file not found

Tags: php, android, mysql

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android-snippets/android-login-and-registration-with-php-and-mysql/) to make a simple login and registration for Android application with MySql. The Android app runs fine until it hit an error when accessing the database (account register).

When I tried to access the php application to make sure that the error is in the Android app, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DbConnect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\AndroidLogin\include\user.php on line 12
```

I'm sure that `db.php` is already included in `user.php`. These are the codes I used from the tutorial: The first one is `index.php`

```
//index.php
<?php

require_once 'include/user.php';

$username = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

// Instance of a User class
$userObject = new User();

// Registration of new user
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);
    $json_registration = $userObject->createNewRegisterUser($username, $hashed_password, $email);
    echo json_encode($json_registration);
}

// User Login
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && empty($email)){
    $hashed_password = md5($password);
    $json_array = $userObject->loginUsers($username, $hashed_password);
    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
?>
```

Next, `config.php`

```
//config.php
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_NAME", "androidlogin");
?>
```

This one is `db.php`

```
// db.php
<?php

include_once 'config.php';

class DbConnect{
    private $connect;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->connect)){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    public function getDb(){
        return $this->connect;
    }
}
?>
```

And the last one is `user.php`

```
// user.php
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

class User{
    private $db;
    private $db_table = "users";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DbConnect();
    }

    public function isLoginExist($username, $password){
        $query = "select * from " . $this->db_table . " where username = '$username' AND password = '$password' Limit 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
            return true;
        }

        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return false;
    }

    public function createNewRegisterUser($username, $password, $email){
        $query = "insert into users (username, password, email, created_at, updated_at) values ('$username', '$password', '$email', NOW(), NOW())";
        $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

        if($inserted == 1){
            $json['success'] = 1;
        }else{
            $json['success'] = 0;
        }

        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());

        return $json;
    }

    public function loginUsers($username, $password){
        $json = array();
        $canUserLogin = $this->isLoginExist($username, $password);

        if($canUserLogin){
            $json['success'] = 1;
        }else{
            $json['success'] = 0;
        }
        return $json;
    }
}
?>
```

My directory looks like this:

```
AndroidLogin
|index.php
|include
 |config.php
 |db.php
 |user.php
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: you are following the wrong tutorial one taht doesn't save passwords in the clar and one taht will expose your site to sql injections

Comment: Someone else have the same issue as you. The author writes "Make sure you have copied this file to your local or remote server." Maybe that could be your problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion: usually, call the file like the class that you declare in it. In WAMP usually it gives some issues, i suggest to you to rename db.php in DbConnect.php

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for the reminder. I'm aware that this kind of method is not secure but it's easy to follow though. I'm new to Android so it really helps.

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine Ah! I never thought of renaming the file with the class name. I did what you said and the error is gone. How do I set that your comment solved my question? P.S: Now new errors are sprouting up. Now it doesn't recognize the constants in `config.php` (Use of undefined constant CONSTANT_NAME)

Comment: just because a tutorial is easy to follow you shouldn't follow a stupid one and if you want the easy way, you should use an existing authentication solution.

Comment: @e4c5 I don't think calling it stupid is appropriate. I know I can use the existing one but like I said I'm new to Android and I have no idea how it works. This kind of tutorial helps me learn the few necessary bits I need to know.

Comment: saving passwords in plain text is not just stupid extremely stupid. Using string concatenation instead of prepared statements in sql is in the same league. Just search stackoverflow

Comment: @e4c5 I don't know if I should keep replying this but I understand your concern. I'm not going to use it just as it is. I'm sure the author of the tutorial didn't really bother with every weakness you pointed up for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: and what makes you think prepared statements are more complex than this method? They are not they are even simpler. That's what makes this tutorial mind numbingly stupid.

Comment: @AceVez i answer with the comment, so you can accept if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, call the file like the class that you declare in it. In WAMP usually it gives some issues, i suggest to you to rename `db.php` in `DbConnect.php`

Answer (score -2):

Make a default (empty) constructor in DbConnect, and make a simple method that would echo something. Try to make new DbConnect instance call that method from User class?

Comment: Does not seem like an answer.

Comment: It isn't. He claims that db.php is already included in user.php. Let's first check that one before going any further.

Comment: If it is not an answer, don't answer. Make a comment instead. That's what @malutki5200 is saying

Comment: I'm not quite sure about difference between an answer and comment in this context. If this, what I said, was the ANSWER to his problem, then the question he posted would be redundant and he'd have to formulate a new one, subsequently making this question answer-less. Does all that really matter that much to you?

Comment: So in the end I was right. He never even made it to the DbConnect class. What now?

Comment: @malutki5200  Not so fast now?

Comment: So, what now ?!?!?